# Debug Java 8 Standard App Engine with Android Studio / IntelliJ?

Tags: google-app-engine, java-8, appcfg

Is it possible to debug to Google App Engine with a Java 8 runtime using Android Studio Google cloud plugin?  Currently getting an error when any of the old whitelisted classes are used.  I know there is gcloud and a new Gradle plugin, however that does not integrate with the Intellij CE (or Android Studio) plugin, so debugging is not possible.

Comment: Not sure about the java details, but in python it's possible to have both GAE and gcloud SDKs installed and mix their usage, for example I'm deploying using the gcloud SDK, but I can still run the GAE SDK development server through pycharm.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect the real issue here.  Appcfg.sh does deploy.  My issue is debugging Java 8 in Android Studio.